# Is it possible to link Code Maps in VS Enterprise 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am trying out the Code Map feature in VS 2017 Enterprise. However the maps get cluttered quickly. One can use the "New Graph from Selection" to create a new graph and then drill down further. However there seems no way to link the parent map to the child map, so navigating from one to another becomes very tricky. I would have expected to be able to put in a file link of some sort.

Any thoughts on this please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one cannot do it in the GUI, one has to add a "reference" attribute to the Node element in the DGML file

```
<Node Id="@29" Category="CodeSchema_Method" Bounds="629.838307291667,-192.520041836548,154.936666666667,25.96" CodeSchemaProperty_IsPrivate="True" DelayedCrossGroupLinksState="Fetched" Label="MyMethod" UseManualLocation="True" Reference = "Graph1_1_1_1.dgml"/>
```

You then get a "go to reference" menu option for the relevant node.

Hope this is helpful to someone.